# How to create a png image from frame buffer in android

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Now iam using the '/dev/graphics/fb0' to get the frame buffer and  iam saving it on sd card using 'cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/screen.raw'.

Now i want convert that raw data into a png image and display on to the screen.is it possible to convert as a png in android code by using (NDK/SDK).

Answer (score 1):

Code to do this can be found in the Android source tree.  The old [screenshot tool](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/cmds/screenshot/screenshot.c) reads from the framebuffer device and saves it to PNG.

Note this does not work on newer devices, which may use hardware composer overlays to avoid writing to a single framebuffer.  On such devices you need to use the [screencap tool](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp) instead.